# Fest test runs very slow after showing content in TreeTable content

Tags: java, swing, treetable, fest

I am working on custom TreeTable Component(extends JTable) in my project. This will have Jtree inside of it. I have overridden paint() in my TreeTable class.

I am using Fest to test. Fest actions(like click, selection and anything) runs very slow after tree table component content is shown in the UI. When i added debug pointer in the code, paint is called recursively and tree Model methods.

I could not figure this out. Would you please let me know what could be causing fest actions to slow down (making it wait for more time)? is it because of repainting? if so how to stop repainting again and again?

NOTE: When i test manually, i don't see any performance issues. it works as normal

Thanks
Robert

Comment: Try to test without your repaint method. So you can see whether it's a problem of your repaint implementation or not. FEST is good lib, but it uses some Swing-hacks which can provide such side effects. By the way which implementation of TreeTable is used in your project (SwingX?, JIDE? GlazedList?). Probably you can switch to another implementation?

Comment: It is taken from somewhere in sun link. I have overridden paint method in Tree class used inside TreeTable. I cant remove paint() method as it does cell rendering with tree node.